# Is there a standard Drupal way to link to 3rd party configuration forms?

Tags: forms, navigation

I am writing a custom module.  On my module's configuration form I would like to provide links to relevant modules' configuration forms; e.g. the cron configuration form.

Is there a standard Drupal way to encode such links?
For instance is there a Drupal function that takes the menu path (eg. 'admin/config/system/cron') and provides an actual URL?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use the [l function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7). [url function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7) is also available but while using in module l is a better option than url .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For instance is there a Drupal function that takes the menu path (eg.
>   'admin/config/system/cron') and provides an actual URL?

Definitely!

```
print l(t('Cron configuration'), 'admin/config/system/cron');
```

Will print an a tag as follows:

```
<a href="/admin/config/system/cron">Cron configuration</a>
```

to the configuration with paths resolved correctly (works well when you have installed Drupal in a sub folder as well - just use the Drupal path).

If you are putting your own text, most likely that you are using `t()` function. 
Example:

```
$form['warning']['#makup'] = t('You need to make sure that you have setup a working !cron',
  array('!cron' => l(t('Cron configuration'), 'admin/config/system/cron')));
```

[`l()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7)  -  Generates the anchor link (`<a href="path/to/page">text</a>`)

[`url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7) -  Returns URL for a given Drupal path (`l()` calls this function to get the correct link)

See function reference for more configuration (absolute URLs, prevent using aliased path, etc)

Comment: Doh, think I got the wrong end of the stick there...

Comment: @Clive Yup...me too >_<

Answer (score 2):

If a module has declared it's config form in the info file, I think you should be able to use [`drupal_parse_info_file();`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_parse_info_file/7).

I'd probably get all the module names into an array, and then just run a `foreach` to get the paths.

Example:

**This is untested code that you should use as an example - there is no array error checking or anything like that:*

```
function MYMODULE_get_config_pages() {
  $config_pages = array();
  $modules = array('cron', 'views', 'ctools', 'panels');

  foreach ($modules as $module) {
    $path = drupal_get_path('module', $module);
    $filename = $module . '.info';

    $info = drupal_parse_info_file($path . '/' . $filename);

    $config_pages[$module] = $info['configuration'];
  }

  return $config_pages;
}
```

This will give you an array of module configuration pages, keyed by module name.

Next you'll want to run those links through [`l()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7)

Example:

```
function MYMODULE_get_config_links($config_pages) {
  $links = array();

  foreach ($config_pages as $module => $uri) {
    // You might want to run $module through t() here or perhaps capitalise it.
    $links[] = l($module, $uri);
  }

  return $links;
}
```

You could probably turn that into a neat little reusable object and bundle it with a module, but the above code should get you started :)

Please note, that I've not written any error checking for modules with no config pages declared in their info file!  You might want to run an [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) somewhere in the first function.